# Failed to compile Swift source files. Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift

```
1.  While reading from /Users/darren/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeCenterMobile-bwpkitagnenydnenhulzpfhbjnvm/Build/Intermediates/WeCenterMobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/WeCenterMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UIView+UserInfo~partial.swiftmodule
2.  While deserializing decl #2 (EXTENSION_DECL)
3.  While deserializing decl #31 (XREF)
4.  Cross-reference to module 'WeCenterMobile'
    ... Msr
    ... UI
    ... _Detail
5.  While deserializing 'Indicator' (ClassDecl #20) 
6.  While deserializing decl #66 (XREF)
7.  Cross-reference to module 'WeCenterMobile'
    ... Msr
    ... UI
    ... in an extension in module 'WeCenterMobile'
    ... AutoExpandingView
8.  While deserializing 'Segment' (ClassDecl #14) 
9.  While deserializing decl #54 (XREF)
10. Cross-reference to module 'WeCenterMobile'
    ... Msr
    ... UI
    ... in an extension in module 'WeCenterMobile'
    ... AutoExpandingView
11. While deserializing 'DefaultSegment' (ClassDecl #17)
```

This is the compiler crash log, anyone could help? I'm using Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.3 Beta 2

There are so much codes so I cannot post them on this page. Please give me some hints to find the errors.

Comment: Do you have a `UIView+UserInfo` file ? Error might come from there.

Comment: I've often had segmentation faults when making a typo in the name of a module I was importing.

And the error message was pretty unhelpful!

Comment: @lchamp: Thanks for your help, but I didn't change it after my lastest commit. Now I've solved the problem by reverting to the previous version...

Comment: I have this problem on Swift 2.2, Xcode 7 as well

Comment: I have seen similar problems increase when I have too many Carthage dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced this issue and managed to fix it by deleting derived data and cleaning the project and build folder.

Hope this solves your issue too.